# How can I make a gif for comparison.cloud in R?

Tags: r, animation, data-visualization, word-cloud

R newbie here.

I have a wordcloud with 7 different classes using comparison.cloud().
What I want to do is to make a GIF which goes like this:

- 1st frame: Nothing is displayed.
- 2nd frame: 1st class is displayed
- 3rd frame: 1st + 2nd classes are displayed
- ..... and so on until I reach the final frame where every class is displayed

The packages I'm using are:

```
library(reshape)
library(NLP)
library(tm)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)
```

I managed to create the GIF by creating a PNG with a wordcloud each time and setting the text color of the classes I didn't want to display same as the background color(messy solution but it was the best I could think of).

I used this code for the GIF.

```
library(magick)
frames <- paste0("", 1:14, ".png")
m <- image_read(frames)
m <- image_animate(m, fps=0.5)
image_write(m, "wordcloud.gif")
```

My problem is that since I create a new wordcloud for each PNG file the positions of the words in the classes get re-arranged and the transitions in the animation look bad.

Is there any way to create this GIF using only one wordcloud? (getting one class at a time for example)

Also, sorry for the long read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make words you don't want to display white, and use `set.seed` to keep the positions constant:

```
library(wordcloud)
library(magick)

words <- c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9)
freq <- seq(1, 1000, len = 62)
n <- length(words)

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  png(paste0('test', i, '.png'))
  set.seed(1234)
  wordcloud(words, freq, colors = c(rep('black', i), rep('white', n - i)))
  dev.off()
}

frames <- paste0("test", seq_len(n), ".png")
m <- image_read(frames)
m <- image_animate(m, fps = 10)
image_write(m, "wordcloud.gif")
```

[image]